# Is there any way to tell if these walls are load bearing from the blueprints?

Tags: walls, kitchens, load-bearing

[image]We want to remove the highlighted walls. Is there any way to tell from the blueprints if these walls are load-bearing?

[image]

Comment: Yes. But you need to provide the blueprints, not a tiny snippet of one sheet showing electrical layout. Show the structural drawings for _all_ levels.

Comment: Unfortunately this is all the county provided me with. I uploaded the full page but I'm assuming this won't help either.

Comment: Not being as fuzzy as it is, anyway. :) Judging by the home's overall layout I can say that it's unlikely that the walls at the doorway are load-bearing, and the kitchen cabinet wall almost certainly is not, but we can only guess. Have someone come by and look at the roof structure and the foundation.

Answer (score 4):

You won't be able to tell from these blueprints because these are the electrical plans and not the structural.